# Nodejs web scraping with cheerio, getting texts unexpected way

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, cheerio

I am newbie at JS and I am trying to do web scraping using cheerio. What I trying to do is getting an specific classes texts

expected output is an array which is:
`["file name 1", "file name 2", "file name 3"]`

what I got is an string:
`"file name 1file name 2file name 3"`

```
const axios = require("axios");
const cheerio = require("cheerio");

const url = "https://avesis.yildiz.edu.tr/mercimek/dokumanlar";

axios(url)
  .then((response) => {
    const html = response.data;
    const $ = cheerio.load(html);
    let title = $("div[class='col-md-8 col-xs-3'] >span").text(); // expected array but got string
    console.log(title);

  })
  .catch(console.error);
```

edit: got rid of the unneccessary parts of the code

edit2: the code in new form

```
 const axios = require("axios");
    const cheerio = require("cheerio");
    
    const url = "https://avesis.yildiz.edu.tr/mercimek/dokumanlar";
    
    axios(url)
      .then((response) => {
        const html = response.data;
        const $ = cheerio.load(html);
        let title = $("div[class='col-md-8 col-xs-3'] >span").text();
        console.log(title)
      })
      .catch(console.error);
```

I am getting an array which contains:
`<span>, <i> , <div>` types

Comment: I don't quite understand the question. Can you indicate in the code with comments what you expect where?

Comment: I've changed the code as you want, I believe. if there is still problem of understanding, I will do my best to explain it better

Comment: What does the html that you load look like?

Comment: you can check the site here: https://avesis.yildiz.edu.tr/mercimek/dokumanlar
I want to get the titles of the announcments by one by

Comment: Problem was answered by reddittors in the link, you can check the answer from [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/node/comments/iit18x/web_scraping_with_cheerio/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3)